# pysnmpv3 decryption the hex data with username and password

Tags: encryption, snmp, pysnmp

My friend gave me a long string which is "snmpHexData", a username, and a password. Then he said to me, Our privacy mode is aes128, and authentication mode is sha. Can you decrypt this snmpv3 data?

I've tried many libraries and Google searches, and I cannot handle this task. Note that: WireShark is working fine.

How can I decrypt this?

I googled alomst every related page, checked some core codes of pysnmp, but couldn't handle with this task...

Comment: With authencation/privacy methods and their passphrases, decrypting the scope section is rather easy. But probably not with PySNMP, as that code base wasn't written in a way that you can use individual methods outside of the context. Sadly you didn't read every related page yet, and sample code in C# is much easier to follow, https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/12.5.3-alpha.2/SharpSnmpLib/Security/AESPrivacyProviderBase.cs#L223